# SELECT DISTINCT showing duplicate dates per customer email

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I am trying to retrieve information for the past ten months, but am having a couple of errors.  First, my query is getting data from as far back as 2013.  Secondly, I am seeing duplicates in my results based on the `PolEffDate` field, like this:

```
EntityID | PolEffDate | EMail | CustNo | Producer | BusinessPhone
abcde-12345-fghij-67890 | 2013-09-24 | somewhere@email.com | 31000 | Bob Builder | 123-456-7890
abcde-12345-fghij-67890 | 2013-12-01 | somewhere@email.com | 31000 | Bob Builder | 123-456-7890
abcde-12345-fghij-67890 | 2014-09-24 | somewhere@email.com | 31000 | Bob Builder | 123-456-7890
```

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     CONVERT(VarChar(36), Customer.CustId) AS EntityID
     , BasicPolInfo.PolEffDate, Customer.EMail, Customer.CustNo
     , (isnull(Employee.Firstname + ' ','') + isnull(Employee.LastName,'')) 
     AS Producer, Employee.BusFullPhone
FROM
     Customer INNER JOIN BasicPolInfo ON Customer.CustId = BasicPolInfo.CustId INNER JOIN
    Transaction ON BasicPolInfo.PolId = Transaction.PolId INNER JOIN
    GeneralBranch ON Customer.GLBrnchCode = GeneralBranch.GLBrnchCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralDepartment ON Customer.GLDeptCode = GeneralDepartment.GLDeptCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralDivision ON Customer.GLDivCode = GeneralDivision.GLDivCode INNER JOIN
    Employee ON BasicPolInfo.ExecCode = Employee.EmpCode
WHERE   
     BasicPolInfo.PolExpDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -10,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)) 
     AND BasicPolInfo.PolExpDate <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
     AND Customer.Active = 'Y'
     AND Customer.typeCust = 'P'
```

Thank you for the help. I will try my best to answer any questions.

Comment: Maybe convert PolExpDate into a DATE instead of converting the comparisons of GETDATE into a VARCHAR

Comment: Your date logic is needlessly complicated, try something like: `BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -10, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: what data type is PolExpDate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel, the duplication you are seeing is caused because you have multiple records in `BasicPolInfo` for each `CustID` value.  You can confirm this by running the following query:

```
SELECT CustID, COUNT(*)
FROM BasicPolInfo
GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Depending on your schema, this may not be an issue - after all, there is probably a perfectly legitimate reason for that!  Multiple policies per Customer is my guess.

To resolve the duplication, I would recommend a `GROUP BY` with `MIN()` or `MAX()`.

Your other issue, that of retrieving data from earlier dates, is because you are selecting the `PolEffDate` (presumably, policy effective date), but filtering the `PolExpDate` (presumably, policy expiration date).  Which are you intending to use?  Policies that have finished sometime in the last ten months could have started much earlier than that.

To resolve the wider date range, reference the same value in your `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses.

Query below (using `MAX()` and `PolExpDate`):

```
SELECT 
     CONVERT(VarChar(36), Customer.CustId) AS EntityID, 
     MAX(BasicPolInfo.PolExpDate) AS PolExpDate, -- note that this is now PolExpDate
     Customer.EMail, 
     Customer.CustNo, 
     (isnull(Employee.Firstname + ' ','') + isnull(Employee.LastName,'')) AS Producer, 
     Employee.BusFullPhone
FROM
    Customer INNER JOIN 
    BasicPolInfo ON Customer.CustId = BasicPolInfo.CustId INNER JOIN
    [Transaction] ON BasicPolInfo.PolId = [Transaction].PolId INNER JOIN
    GeneralBranch ON Customer.GLBrnchCode = GeneralBranch.GLBrnchCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralDepartment ON Customer.GLDeptCode = GeneralDepartment.GLDeptCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralDivision ON Customer.GLDivCode = GeneralDivision.GLDivCode INNER JOIN
    Employee ON BasicPolInfo.ExecCode = Employee.EmpCode
WHERE   
     BasicPolInfo.PolExpDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -10,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)) 
     AND BasicPolInfo.PolExpDate <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
     AND Customer.Active = 'Y'
     AND Customer.typeCust = 'P'
GROUP BY 
     CONVERT(VarChar(36), Customer.CustId), 
     Customer.EMail, 
     Customer.CustNo, 
     (isnull(Employee.Firstname + ' ','') + isnull(Employee.LastName,'')), 
     Employee.BusFullPhone
```

Comment: Fair point - it might be an accurate way to read the data, despite what seems to be confusion over the ten months.  I think a simplified `WHERE` clause would be good for the OP to incorporate regardless, but didn't want to add it in until I knew if I was on the right track.